# BSP tree traversal in relation to position?

Tags: tree, bsp-tree

This is more of a conceptual question than a coding question. I have figured out the basic concepts of a BSP tree but am having trouble wrapping my head around the positioning. I have figured out that to find my current location in the BSP tree, I keep recursively iterating through the tree moving to the right if I am in front of the split plane, and left if I am behind it. When I eventually hit a leaf node, that is where I am in the world.

Now, in terms of rendering, if I had to render from front to back, would I start at the right side of the tree and render all the way recursively until I hit the last node on the left side. What about back to front? Would it be the opposite?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to draw back to front which is the `Painters algorithm` you'd traverse left nodes first when you are in front, then render and then traverse right nodes.

For front to back it would be the opposite.

Comment: Your wording has confused me a bit. So with Painters algorithm, I am traversing from the left until I get to my current location, then render that and then traverse right and render that as well?

Comment: Yes basically that is how it works. It's a depth first traversal going left first painting on the way up befote traversing right. So at each node you do this: determine whether you are in front or back, then you would traverse further left or right resp. then paint then traverse right or left resp.